# X-Frame-Options and Content-Security-Policy for frames in Firefox

Tags: security, firefox, frame, content-security-policy, x-frame-options

[Content Security Policy specification says](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP11/#frame-ancestors-and-frame-options)

> The frame-ancestors directive obsoletes the X-Frame-Options header. If a resource has both policies, the frame-ancestors policy SHOULD be enforced and the X-Frame-Options policy SHOULD be ignored.

So from my understanding if both `Content-Security-Policy` and `X-Frame-Options` headers are present, then `X-Frame-Options` should be ignored.

I have a web app with both headers, and looks like Firefox 38 is ignores `Content-Security-Policy` header and uses `X-Frame-Options` header instead.

My sample headers are:

```
Content-Security-Policy:frame-ancestors 'self' local.com *.local.com 
X-Frame-Options:Allow-From http://local.com
```

I want that my frame should be accessed from local.com and all subdomains. Local.com is just example. If `X-Frame-Options` header is present, then it allows just http://local.com, but if i remove it, then Firefox uses `Content-Security-Policy` header and works fine for domain and subdomains.

Does it mean that Firefox isn't implementing this part? Or it's just too new specification and Firefox doesn't implement it yet? Is there any other way to force `Content-Security-Policy` header usage?

I know that Chrome works fine with `Content-Security-Policy` and IE can work just with `X-Frame-Options`, but looks like i can't combine both headers, as Firefox works not in right way.

One possible way is to sent `X-Frame-Options` just for IE, and `Content-Security-Policy` for all other, but is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`frame-ancestors` only appeared in CSP Level 2 (see the [changelog](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#changes-from-level-1)) so it's very likely that Firefox 38 just hasn't implemented it yet.

You can verify that quite easily by watching the JavaScript console - the browser will display warnings about each of the CSP directives it doesn't understand.

You can also download Firefox from the *beta* channel and see if it makes difference, but obviously it won't help much if you just want to build a interoperable solution for production website...

Comment: I thought that it's a new one, but hoped that i missed something. So looks like i would need to send headers based on browser. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Firefox 47.0 -- the same

Comment: Same on Firefox 50.1 - apparently Mozilla hasn't implemented the official CSP spec yet. :/

Comment: There is a bug at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1024557 for this, vote for it to get it pushed through.

Comment: on a similar note, chrome won't implement the "X-Frame-Options:Allow-From", see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129139