# How does Content-Security-Policy work with X-Frame-Options?

Tags: http, http-headers, content-security-policy, x-frame-options

Does `Content-Security-Policy` ignore `X-Frame-Options`, returned by a server, or is `X-Frame-Options` still primary?

Assuming that I have:

- a website http://a.com with `X-Frame-Options: DENY`
- and a website http://b.com with `Content-Security-Policy: frame-src a.com`

will browser load this frame?

It is unclear.
On the one hand, http://a.com explicitly denies framing.
On the other hand, http://b.com explicitly allows framing for http://a.com.

Comment: Note that neither CSP nor XFO header blocks loading the site. The site *will be loaded* in that the request will be made. It's just that after loading it the browser will notice the headers and *will not display* the site inside a frame.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The [`frame-src` CSP directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives#frame-src) (which is deprecated and replaced by `child-src`) determines what sources can be used in a frame on a page.

The `X-Frame-Options` response header, on the other hand, determines what other pages can use that page in an iframe.

In your case, `http://a.com` with `X-Frame-Options: DENY` indicates that no other page can use it in a frame. It does not matter what `http://b.com` has in its CSP -- no page can use `http://a.com` in a frame.

---

The place where `X-Frame-Options` intersects with CSP is via the [`frame-ancestors` directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives#frame-ancestors). From the [CSP specificiation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#frame-ancestors-and-frame-options) (emphasis mine):

> This directive is similar to the `X-Frame-Options` header that several
>   user agents have implemented. The `'none'` source expression is
>   roughly equivalent to that header’s `DENY`, `'self'` to `SAMEORIGIN`,
>   and so on. The major difference is that many user agents implement
>   `SAMEORIGIN` such that it only matches against the top-level
>   document’s location. This directive checks each ancestor. If any
>   ancestor doesn’t match, the load is cancelled. [[RFC7034]](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#biblio-rfc7034)
>
> **The `frame-ancestors` directive obsoletes the `X-Frame-Options` header. If a resource has both policies, the `frame-ancestors` policy SHOULD be enforced and the `X-Frame-Options` policy SHOULD be ignored.**

An [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014595/x-frame-options-and-content-security-policy-for-frames-in-firefox) indicated this did not work in Firefox at that time but hopefully things have changed now.

---

## UPDATE April 2018:

> Content Security Policy: Directive ‘child-src’ has been deprecated. Please use directive ‘worker-src’ to control workers, or directive ‘frame-src’ to control frames respectively.

Looks like `child-src` is now the deprecated one and `frame-src` is back.

Comment: "The frame-src CSP directive (which is deprecated and replaced by child-src)" - What is the source of this statement ?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#directive-frame-src -- "The frame-src directive is deprecated. Authors who wish to govern nested browsing contexts SHOULD use the child-src directive instead." Looks like it is planned to be undeprecated in CSP3 -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-src#Specifications and https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#directive-child-src

Comment: Yes, Firefox did not respect that, last time I checked was a few months ago, but now it works as expected.

Comment: As far as I can tell now, neither `child-src` nor `frame-src` is deprecated in the current level 3 draft. If I understand correctly, `child-src` encompasses both `frame-src` and `worker-src`, but honestly, at this point, my brain is melting trying to figure out what's what.

Answer (score 16):

None of your hypotheses are universally true.

- Chrome ignores `X-Frame-Options`.
- Safari 9 and below ignore CSP `frame-ancestors`.
- Safari 10-12 respect the CSP `frame-ancestors` directive, but *prioritize* `X-Frame-Options` if both are specified.

Comment: This is true for Safari 11 and Safari 12 too. As of September 2018 X-Frame-Options is still prioritized over CSP.

Comment: @NathanCH, Yes, Exactly.. Safari12 prioritizing XFO over CSP. Now we are facing problem since we are using SFO-sameorigin and CSP both in our code as "X-FRAME-OPTIONS"--> SAMEORIGIN
"Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors 'self' *.abcd.net". How can we specify URL with SFO ?

Comment: I need a citation on Chrome ignoring X-Frame-Options. The data I can find suggests it ignores ALLOW-FROM, but is fine for other values.

Comment: IOS Safari 13 ignores x-frame-options in favour of "CSP frame ancestors"

Comment: Hi. At this moment moment in time, this answer is at least partly false, as [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#browser_compatibility) is widely supported in literally all browsers, from what counts as ancient versions, even Internet Explorer 8 (!)

Answer (score 3):

The answer was found by testing in practice.
I have created two web-sites and reproduced the described situation.

It seems like X-Frame-Options is primary.
If target server denies framing, then client website cannot display this page in `iframe` whichever values of `Content-Security-Policy` are set.

However, I haven't found any confirmations in documentation.

Tested on Chrome 54 and IE 11.