# Http security header - X-Frame-Options and CSP what takes precedence?

Tags: http, http-headers, content-security-policy, x-frame-options

I need to allow my web application to be iframed.

Both headers will be on the same response. This is different from [How does Content-Security-Policy work with X-Frame-Options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373771/how-does-content-security-policy-work-with-x-frame-options) which is referring to headers on both the parent page and the iframed page.

Currently, it has the x-frame-options set as sameorigin. I cannot modify this due to being inherited from a parent project.
However, I am able to modify the Content-Security-Policy to add a frame ancestor so I can add the option I need to allow Iframing.

My headers will look like this

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://theHostOfMyIframe.com
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

My question is, will the CSP override the xframe option to allow my site to be iframed?

Comment: Both headers will be on the same response. This is different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373771/how-does-content-security-policy-work-with-x-frame-options

Comment: While, the question is slightly different, the accepted answer on that question does answer your question as well.